# I made a picture of you

Tags: discussion

I love coffee; it is great. Happiness and coffee.

Happy Coffee Day!

[image]

Comment: I do love some stats. Clearly we need to do some heavy-duty question answering though!

Comment: I think the statistics should use delta values instead of absolute values. E.g. in the fourth graph, it is obvious that the number of questions will rise in time. The important values are questions per day and answers per day.